# Erro em código javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

Não sei de onde vem o erro do meu codigo, ja revisei ele e não consigo achar a falha, acontece que as funções que eram pra ser chamadas não estão sendo executadas, segue o código:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv = "content-type" content = "text/html;charset = utf-8"/>
    <script>
    var result1, lucro1, parcela1, valor1;

    function porcentagem()
    {
    //Fórmula para descobrir a porcentagem
    result1 = parseFloat(form1.valor1.value) * parseFloat(form1.porce.value) / 100;
    //Exibindo o resultado na caixa com o sinal de “R$” (concatenar)
    form1.result.value = "R$ " + result1;
    //Cálculo do Lucro obtido através do empréstimo.
    lucro1 = parseFloat(form1.valor1.value) + result1;
    //Exibindo o Lucro com o sinal de “R$” (concatenar)
    form1.lucro.value = "R$ " + lucro1;
    }
    function parcelar()
    {
    if(parseInt(form1.dividir.value)==2)
    {
    //Calculando o valor da parcela a ser paga através do fator.
    parcela1 = (parseFloat(lucro1) * 0.536412616967654).toFixed(2);
    //Exibindo na tela com o sinal de “R$” (concatenar)
    form1.parcela.value = "R$ " + parcela1;
    //Calculando o valor total a ser pago
    valor1 = (parseFloat(parcela1) * 2).toFixed(2);
    //Exibindo na tela com o sinal de “R$” (concatenar)
    form1.valor.value = "R$ " + valor1;
    }
    else if(parseInt(form1.dividir.value)==3)
    {
    parcela1 = (parseFloat(lucro1) * 0.365517074106242).toFixed(2);
    form1.parcela.value = "R$ " + parcela1;
    valor1 = (parseFloat(parcela1) * 3).toFixed(2);
    form1.valor.value = "R$ " + valor1;
    }
    else if(parseInt(form1.dividir.value)==4)
    {
    parcela1 = (parseFloat(lucro1) * 0.280159443141692).toFixed(2);
    form1.parcela.value = "R$ " + parcela1;
    valor1 = (parseFloat(parcela1) * 4).toFixed(2);
    form1.valor.value = "R$ " + valor1;
    }
    else if(parseInt(form1.dividir.value)==5)
    {
    parcela1 = (parseFloat(lucro1) * 0.229017159132115).toFixed(2);
    form1.parcela.value = "R$ " + parcela1;
    valor1 = (parseFloat(parcela1) * 5).toFixed(2);
    form1.valor.value = "R$ " + valor1;
    }
    else
    {
    alert(“Desculpe-nos, impossível parcelar!”);
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name = "form1">
    Digite o valor:<input type = "text" name = "valor1" value = "">
    <br><br>
    Digite a porcentagem:<input type = "text" name = "porce" value = "">
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <input type = "button" name = "calcular" onclick = "porcentagem()" value = "Calcular">
    <input type = "reset" value = "Limpar" >
    <br><br>
    Valor do lucro:<input type = "text" name = "lucro" value = "">Preço total:<input type = "text" name = "precototal" value = "">
    <br><br>
    Quantas vezes deseja dividir ?<input type = "text" name = "dividir" value = "">
    <br><br>
    <input type = "button" name = "parcelar" onclick = "parcelar()" value = "Parcelar">
    <br><br>
    Parcela por mês:<input type = "text" name = "parcela" value = "">Valor Total com Juros:<input type = "text" name = "valor" value = "">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Que erro aparece no console?

Comment: @Bacco Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token nas linhas 54 e 66 respectivamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Corrigida referência ao campo `result` que não existe;
- renomeada função parcelar, para não conflitar com o `form`;
- arrumadas aspas do `alert()`.

Segue o código corrigido:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset = utf-8">
  <script>
    var result1, lucro1, parcela1, valor1;
    function porcentagem() {
      //Fórmula para descobrir a porcentagem
      result1 = parseFloat(form1.valor1.value) * parseFloat(form1.porce.value) / 100;
      //Exibindo o resultado na caixa com o sinal de “R$” (concatenar)
      form1.precototal.value = "R$ " + result1;
      //Cálculo do Lucro obtido através do empréstimo.
      lucro1 = parseFloat(form1.valor1.value) + result1;
      //Exibindo o Lucro com o sinal de “R$” (concatenar)
      form1.lucro.value = "R$ " + lucro1;
    }
    function parcelarValor() {
      if (parseInt(form1.dividir.value) == 2) {
        //Calculando o valor da parcela a ser paga através do fator.
        parcela1 = (parseFloat(lucro1) * 0.536412616967654).toFixed(2);
        //Exibindo na tela com o sinal de “R$” (concatenar)
        form1.parcela.value = "R$ " + parcela1;
        //Calculando o valor total a ser pago
        valor1 = (parseFloat(parcela1) * 2).toFixed(2);
        //Exibindo na tela com o sinal de “R$” (concatenar)
        form1.valor.value = "R$ " + valor1;
      } else if (parseInt(form1.dividir.value) == 3) {
        parcela1 = (parseFloat(lucro1) * 0.365517074106242).toFixed(2);
        form1.parcela.value = "R$ " + parcela1;
        valor1 = (parseFloat(parcela1) * 3).toFixed(2);
        form1.valor.value = "R$ " + valor1;
      } else if (parseInt(form1.dividir.value) == 4) {
        parcela1 = (parseFloat(lucro1) * 0.280159443141692).toFixed(2);
        form1.parcela.value = "R$ " + parcela1;
        valor1 = (parseFloat(parcela1) * 4).toFixed(2);
        form1.valor.value = "R$ " + valor1;
      } else if (parseInt(form1.dividir.value) == 5) {
        parcela1 = (parseFloat(lucro1) * 0.229017159132115).toFixed(2);
        form1.parcela.value = "R$ " + parcela1;
        valor1 = (parseFloat(parcela1) * 5).toFixed(2);
        form1.valor.value = "R$ " + valor1;
      } else {
        alert("Desculpe-nos, impossível parcelar!");
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form1">
    Digite o valor:<input type="text" name="valor1" value="">
    <br><br> Digite a porcentagem:<input type="text" name="porce" value="">
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" name="calcular" onclick="porcentagem()" value="Calcular">
    <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
    <br><br> Valor do lucro:<input type="text" name="lucro" value="">Preço total:<input type="text" name="precototal" value="">
    <br><br> Quantas vezes deseja dividir ?<input type="text" name="dividir" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" name="parcelar" onclick="parcelarValor()" value="Parcelar">
    <br><br> Parcela por mês:<input type="text" name="parcela" value="">Valor Total com Juros:<input type="text" name="valor" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/ameZBb)**.

Comment: Sensacional, mas nao entendi mt bem eu olhei aqui e meu alert está parecido com o seu

Comment: @CaioVieira Parecido está, não está igual ;) . Veja a diferença: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d65S5.png

Comment: achei que só existia um tipo de aspas... o que poderia resultar nesse erro ? ctrl c + ctrl v ?

Comment: control c + control v de wordpress ou outras coisas do tipo, que mexem onde não deve no código ;) - Ou mesmo editores de texto como word, que fazem "aspas bonitas"

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.