# Pegar valores calculados de dois inputs e fazer subtração para outro input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário que tem um campo com valor preenchido do banco. Neste formulário, tenho que fazer 2 contas de porcentagem, pegar estes dois valores somar e por fim pegar o valor iniciar e subtrai da soma das porcentagens.

Montei os campos, mas o `javascript` não consegui funcionar. Pode ser com `JQuery`?

```js
$("#percentual1").change(function () {
                    var valor = $("#valor").val();                     
                    var resultado1 = valor * (parseInt($(this).val()) / 100);
                    var resultado1Arrendodado = parseFloat(resultado1.toFixed(2));
                    $("#valor1").val(resultado1Arrendodado);
                    var ValorFinal1 = parseFloat($('#valor1').val());
                    var Valor1Arrendodado = parseFloat(ValorFinal1.toFixed(2));
                    var Valor2 = parseFloat(0.00);
                    var TotalSobra = Valor1Arrendodado + Valor2;
                    if (Number.isNaN(TotalSobra)) {
                        TotalSobra = 0;
                        $('#valorSobra').val(TotalSobra);
                    } else {
                        $('#valorSobra').val(TotalSobra);
                    }
                });
                $("#percentual2").change(function () {
                    var valor = $("#valor").val();
                    var resultado2 = valor * (parseInt($(this).val()) / 100);
                    var resulado2Arrendodado = parseFloat(resultado2.toFixed(2));
                    $("#valor2").val(resulado2Arrendodado);
                    var Valor1 = parseFloat($('#valor1').val());
                    var Valor1Arrendodado = parseFloat(Valor1.toFixed(2));
                    var Valor2 = parseFloat($('#valor2').val());
                    var Valor2Arrendodado = parseFloat(Valor2.toFixed(2));
                    var TotalSobra = Valor1Arrendodado + Valor2Arrendodado;
                    if (Number.isNaN(TotalSobra)) {
                        TotalSobra = 0;
                        $('#valorSobra').val(TotalSobra);
                    } else {
                        $('#valorSobra').val(TotalSobra);
                    }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>                               
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor"  value="69.00" readonly >
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="percentual1">1ºPercentual (%)</label>                                
<input type="text" class="form-control " name="percentual1" id="percentual1" title="Informe o percentual" placeholder="0.00 %"  >
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="valor1">Valor 1</label>                                
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor1" id="valor1"  placeholder="0.00" readonly >
</div>                                    
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>                                
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor"  value="69.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly >
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="percentual2">2º Percentual (%)</label>                               
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="percentual2" id="percentual2" placeholder="0.00%"  >
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">      
 <label for="valor2">Valor 2</label>                                
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor2" id="valor2"  placeholder="0.00" readonly >
 </div>                                    
 </div>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>                                
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name=valor" id="valor"  value="69.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly >
                                    </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="valorSobra">Valor Sobra</label>                                
<input type="text" class="form-control " name="valorSobra" id="valorSobra" >
 </div>                                    
 </div>
```

Comment: @Sergio Não é a mesma coisa. Estranho dizer que está duplicado!

Comment: Amanda, se não for o mesmo problema reabrimos claro. Podes explicar melhor a diferença entre as duas?

Comment: @Sergio, pelo exemplo que você passou, é calculo de porcentagem. Meu problema seria outro. Preciso fazer a conta de porcentagem em dois inputs, somar esses valores e por fim uma subtração. Exemplo: 50 (este é o valor inicial) . 10% de 50 + 5% de 50 . Somo estes dois valores e quero mostrar o valor de 50 - (porcentagem 1 + porcentagem 2) . Jesus... tô doida pra resolver isso. Já tentei outros exemplos e este que você passou não deu certo. Obrigada

Comment: Qual é a parte que não consegues resolver?

Comment: Se a pergunta indicada não bastar, tem essa outra aqui que tem praticamente todas as operações matemáticas que você possa precisar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162532/70 - Se tiver uma parte em específico que não consegue resolver, queira [edit] a pergunta e deixar clara onde está a dúvida exata. E não esqueça de por seu JavaScript, e descrever o que acontece de errado, senão não tem como achar o erro.

Comment: @Sergio fiz as modificações sugeridas. Minha dúvida é que o código funciona usando duas casas decimais... porem se insiro 3% no percentual1 e 2% no percentual 2... recebo um valor com várias casas.

Comment: Use  $('#valorSobra').val(TotalSobra.toFixed(2))

Comment: Amanda! Reabri. Vou responder mais logo também para tentar clarificar.

Comment: @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba já fiz isso. Continua mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como disse no comentário .toFixed(2) adicionando o toFixed ele vai arredondar o valor.

Aqui segue o código em funcionamento.

```js
$("#percentual1").change(function () {
                    var valor = $("#valor").val();                     
                    var resultado1 = valor * (parseInt($(this).val()) / 100);
                    var resultado1Arrendodado = parseFloat(resultado1.toFixed(2));
                    $("#valor1").val(resultado1Arrendodado);
                    var ValorFinal1 = parseFloat($('#valor1').val());
                    var Valor1Arrendodado = parseFloat(ValorFinal1.toFixed(2));
                    var Valor2 = parseFloat(0.00);
                    var TotalSobra = Valor1Arrendodado + Valor2;
                    if (Number.isNaN(TotalSobra)) {
                        TotalSobra = 0;
                        $('#valorSobra').val(TotalSobra);
                    } else {
                        $('#valorSobra').val(TotalSobra);
                    }
                });
                $("#percentual2").change(function () {
                    var valor = $("#valor").val();
                    var resultado2 = valor * (parseInt($(this).val()) / 100);
                    var resulado2Arrendodado = parseFloat(resultado2.toFixed(2));
                    $("#valor2").val(resulado2Arrendodado);
                    var Valor1 = parseFloat($('#valor1').val());
                    var Valor1Arrendodado = parseFloat(Valor1.toFixed(2));
                    var Valor2 = parseFloat($('#valor2').val());
                    var Valor2Arrendodado = parseFloat(Valor2.toFixed(2));
                    var TotalSobra = Valor1Arrendodado + Valor2Arrendodado;
                    if (Number.isNaN(TotalSobra)) {
                        TotalSobra = 0;
                        $('#valorSobra').val(TotalSobra.toFixed(2));
                    } else {
                        $('#valorSobra').val(TotalSobra.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>                               
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor"  value="69.00" readonly >
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="percentual1">1ºPercentual (%)</label>                                
<input type="text" class="form-control " name="percentual1" id="percentual1" title="Informe o percentual" placeholder="0.00 %"  >
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="valor1">Valor 1</label>                                
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor1" id="valor1"  placeholder="0.00" readonly >
</div>                                    
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>                                
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor"  value="69.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly >
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="percentual2">2º Percentual (%)</label>                               
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="percentual2" id="percentual2" placeholder="0.00%"  >
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">      
 <label for="valor2">Valor 2</label>                                
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor2" id="valor2"  placeholder="0.00" readonly >
 </div>                                    
 </div>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>                                
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name=valor" id="valor"  value="69.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly >
                                    </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="valorSobra">Valor Sobra</label>                                
<input type="text" class="form-control " name="valorSobra" id="valorSobra" >
 </div>                                    
 </div>
```